# What is the default font in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, fonts

I would like to know what is the default font in visual studio 2013 to use it in an other IDE.

Thanks!

Comment: Its the black theme, here is a picture!!! http://i.stack.imgur.com/6Wm80.png

Comment: Why don't you just look?  Tools + Options, Environment, Font and Colors.

Comment: Hey Hans. It's because I havn't VS 2013 anymore.

Answer (score 23):

It's **Consolas** with size 10.
You can check it on VS 2013 (Tools > Option > Environment > Fonts and Colors).

But, since you don't have it anymore, may this picture can be help.

[image]